# how to escape white space in Android Studio link to SDK/NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, escaping, andengine

I recently am taking development in Android using `Android Studio 1.5.1` (AS) and I'm really beginner in this area.

My last project is about Game app using AndEngine. Before this, I faced several problem, from importing AndEngine with AS, setting `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`, and then downloaded the NDK.

After solved all that, now I'm facing white spaces problem in NDK location. I placed my NDK in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\ndk-bundle`

How do I solved the white space?

Comment: I have never tried this myself, but maybe using the short path alias will work: `ndk=c:\PROGRA~1\Android\android-sdk\ndk-bundle`. At any rate, this is not a good practice. I strongly suggest to move Android SDK out of admin-only `Program Files` directory: it will be auto-updated regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since no one answered this question, I will give you updates regarding what happened after :

As a workaround, I decided to move the directory which contains all NDKs into C:\ , so it will looks like

```
C:\Android\android-ndk
```

With this, I no longer have problem with whitespaces on NDK directory address, and also helps me accessing NDKs, since now they got short address